# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in spark when applying aggregate functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to do some transformations on a data set. After reading the data set when performing `df.show()` operations, I am getting the rows listed in spark shell. But when I try to do `df.count` or any aggregate functions, I am getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.

```
val itpostsrow = sc.textFile("/home/jayk/Downloads/spark-data")

import scala.util.control.Exception.catching    
import java.sql.Timestamp

implicit class StringImprovements(val s:String) {
      def toIntSafe = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) 
 opt    s.toInt
      def toLongsafe = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]) 
 opt s.toLong
      def toTimeStampsafe = catching(classOf[IllegalArgumentException])       opt Timestamp.valueOf(s)
      }

case class Post(commentcount:Option[Int],lastactivitydate:Option[java.sql.Timestamp],ownerUserId:Option[Long],body:String,score:Option[Int],creattiondate:Option[java.sql.Timestamp],viewcount:Option[Int],title:String,tags:String,answerCount:Option[Int],acceptedanswerid:Option[Long],posttypeid:Option[Long],id:Long)

def stringToPost(row:String):Post = {
      val r = row.split("~")

      Post(r(0).toIntSafe,
           r(1).toTimeStampsafe,
           r(2).toLongsafe,
           r(3),
           r(4).toIntSafe,
           r(5).toTimeStampsafe,
           r(6).toIntSafe,
           r(7),
           r(8),
           r(9).toIntSafe,
           r(10).toLongsafe,
           r(11).toLongsafe,
           r(12).toLong)
   }
   
val itpostsDFcase1 = itpostsrow.map{x=>stringToPost(x)}
val itpostsDF = itpostsDFcase1.toDF()
```

Comment: you are declared all the variables in `case class` with `option` type but while in map function simply creating  `post` class without `Some(r(0))`

Comment: Based on that code, you'll see that error if your source file has any blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `stringToPost()` might cause a Java error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the text file contains some empty row or if the number of fields after the split is not 13.

Due to Spark's lazy evaluation one notices such errors only when performing an action like `count`.